# Como criar um volume de um unico arquivo no docker?

Tags: docker

Estou querendo sincronizar um arquivo que está dentro do meu container com o meu host. Pensei em simplesmente criar um volume para o arquivo, ficando dessa maneira:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
    deathrun:
        image: "ceifa/lory-gmod-deathrun"
        volumes:
            - ./stateful/deathrun/sv.db:/server/garrysmod/sv.db
        restart: always
        tty: true
```

Porém, como o arquivo não existe no host na primeira vez que ele é executado, está sendo criado automaticamente uma pasta no lugar do arquivo e dando o seguinte erro:

> ERROR: for deathrun  Cannot start service deathrun: "..." caused "not a directory": unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type

Como fazer com que ele pegue o arquivo do container ao invés de tentar cria-lo no host?

Comment: Conseguiu verificar a resposta? Não esqueça de aceitá-la caso  esteja satisfeito com a mesma.

Answer (score 1):

Para sincronizar um único ficheiro deves utilizar o caminho absoluto na definição do volume. Por exemplo:

```
volumes:
  - /home/user/stateful/deathrun/sv.db:/server/garrysmod/sv.db
```

ou então

```
volumes:
  - $pwd/stateful/deathrun/sv.db:/server/garrysmod/sv.db
```

Answer (score 1):

Há algumas diferenças em como os volumes funcionam em hosts Windows e Linux/Mac.

Caso esteja usando Windows (host), **NÃO** é possível mapear arquivos, somente diretórios.

E de todo modo, seja em Windows ou não, o ideal é criar o diretório ou o arquivo *antes* de usar o mapeamento, caso contário o Docker assumirá que é um diretório e poderá criá-lo (https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/13121).

Comment: O triste é ter que ficar criando arquivo antes de executar o container. Gostaria que fosse totalmente plug-n-play. Será que não tem outra forma?

Comment: Vc pode mapear um diretório e deixe a aplicação criar o arquivo.

Comment: @Francisco Vc pode mapear um diretório e deixe a aplicação criar o arquivo.